# Android/iPhone webkit, event triggered on keyboard pop?

Tags: events, mobile, keyboard, webkit

On mobile webkit, when focusing on a text input field, the keyboard pops up.
Is there any known event to bind on at the end of the keyboard slide animation??

Comment: Relative articles:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593139/ipad-web-app-detect-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript-in-safari

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556933/screen-styling-when-virtual-keyboard-is-active

Answer (score 4):

so apparently not: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5

I found the most useful information on this other thread: [iPad Web App: Detect Virtual Keyboard Using JavaScript in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593139/ipad-web-app-detect-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript-in-safari)

on Android, we can detect that the keypad is up using the window.innerHeight value, but not on iPhon, the value is not updated... (which also does not help to align stuff at the bottom..)

so I personally just assume the keyboard is popped up 700ms after a text input is entered... ugly, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
    window.onblur = function(e) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    };
```

This is my solution, which works fine, if someone pressed the "closekeyboard" for iOS.