# Detect MS Surface Virtual Keyboard in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-events, surface

Is there a way to detect when the virtual keyboard of the MS Surface is being displayed in a web page via Javascript.  The virtual keyboard is covering up the active text field on a page, and I need to be able to detect this so that I can re-layout the page to work better with the remaining window area.

Comment: possible duplicate of [screen styling when virtual keyboard is active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556933/screen-styling-when-virtual-keyboard-is-active)

Comment: This is different because it deals with windows and not android/ios which handle the keyboard differently (they allow browser/app scrolling by default when the keyboard appears, windows does not)

Comment: Where you able to find a solution to this? I am facing this exact same issue.

Comment: @sigillum_conf I don't recall exactly, this was so long ago.  I don't think I was able to find a solution.