# Resize web page when Microsoft Surface Virtual Keyboard is on screen

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, keyboard

I am developing an application that is going to be used on Microsoft surface tablets (mostly) and I am having an issue with the virtual keyboard. Currently, when the user touches an input field the keyboard opens up and practically covers more than 50% of the screen leaving all other contents of the site covered by the keyboard. I am trying to find a way to make it responsive (I am using bootstrap) as to make the site move accordingly when the keyboard is selected. Another user posted a similar question but had no replies except for one that stated that it might be a duplicate based on mobile devices (which is different considering that it is to be used on a tablet that resembles a laptop more than a mobile device)

The question was originally asked here :
[Detect MS Surface Virtual Keyboard in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997889/detect-ms-surface-virtual-keyboard-in-javascript)

Are there any ways of going around this? been searching for a while to no avail. I have tried to use something such as :

```
var ieX;
if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(window, "ActiveXObject") && !window.ActiveXObject) {
    // is IE11
    console.log("Internet Explorer detected");
    ieX = true;
    if (ieX) {
         document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height='+window.innerHeight+', initial-scale=1.0">');
    }
}
```

which is basically pointless considering that a) I am already using bootstrap and b) even if I add the meta tag to the main template file it continues to be pointless due to bootstrap's built in responsiveness.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Edit for clarification: Yes, the code that finds out the user agent is for IE 11 because we are a godless company and that is what I am being forced to test the code for at the moment.

Edit for duplicate mark: Microsoft Surface deals with keyboards in a way which is different to that of Android and IOS, thus making the solutions in the duplicate link(which was already originally included by me with an explanation...) as not valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [screen styling when virtual keyboard is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556933/screen-styling-when-virtual-keyboard-is-active)

Comment: @jmargolisvt this deals with windows and not android or ios (those two deal with keyboards differently) :)