# How to avoid screen resizing when soft keyboard is showing?

Tags: html, css

I am building a mobile web app and I am having an issue when the soft keyboard pops up.

Currently I am re-sizing images based on screen height media-queries. The problem is that when the soft keyboard is showing the media-query does not apply to that condition anymore.

Is there a way to not affect the screen size when the soft keyboard is active to not mess up the styles? Maybe make the keyboard behave like a popup to not affect the original screen?

Comment: Have a look at this. Hope this can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556933/screen-styling-when-virtual-keyboard-is-active