# is it possible to detect a mobile keyboard

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to detect a keyboard of a smartphone when it comes up.

now i got this, if the input is focussed then it does something

```
<script>
$( "#gebruikersnaam" ).focus(function() {
    $("#header").css("display", "none");
});
$( "#gebruikersnaam" ).focusout(function() {
    $("#header").css("display", "block");
});
$( "#wachtwoord" ).focus(function() {
    //alert( "Wachtwoord" );
});
$( "#hwachtwoord" ).focus(function() {
    //alert( "herhaal wachtwoord" );
});
</script>
```

is there a way if the keyboard is coming that jquery or css can detect it?
this code works for 80% but if i use the back button instead of unfocus the code doesn't work.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593139/ipad-web-app-detect-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript-in-safari

Comment: thats the same that i coded above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270659/detect-virtual-keyboard-vs-hardware-keyboard  maybe get some ideas off of this?

Comment: Here is also a workaround I found online..http://jsfiddle.net/UHdCw/8/ . Basically detects if screen size changes and adds/ removes class based on it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196195/android-iphone-webkit-event-triggered-on-keyboard-pop