# Autocomplete force pac-container above search box

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, hidden, search-box

I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

I am using google.map.places.Autocomplete and its all working fine, but due to app/screen sizes the pac-container with the returned search listings is behind the devices virtual keyboard - and thus on about half of the devices I have tested the user can't see the returned address list.  Obviously you don't want the pac-container in front of the keyboard because then various keyboard keys will be hidden.

How can I force the pac-container to appear above (and scroll up) the search/input box?

Comment: Maybe you can provide some code, test case to start helping you, because everyone can imagine and create scenario he want !

Comment: You could try to detect when the keyboard is active, and limit the height of the pac-container to the new `window.innerHeight`, while making it scrollable so that overflowing results can be found. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600040/jquery-js-html5-change-page-content-when-keyboard-is-visible-on-mobile-devices

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to check when the keyboard opens and then minus margin the page a bit.

```
body.keyboardopen {
     margin-top: -@keyboardheight;
}
```