# Load different stylesheet if keyboard is present on device (javascript detect)

Tags: javascript, load, detect

I am trying to load a different CSS layout in case there is a physical keyboard on the device (q10.css). In case there is no keyboard, the default one is used (normalCss). For some reason the stylesheets are not loaded:

```
<script>
    var normalCss = document.createElement("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/main.css\" />");
    var q10Css = document.createElement("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/q10.css\" />");

    if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Kbd") != -1) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(q10Css);
            }
    else {
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(normalCss);
            }
</script>
```

*any help is highly appreciated :) Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270659/detect-virtual-keyboard-vs-hardware-keyboard

Comment: navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Kbd") will not detect a keyboard. i have one and i get -1...

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you create elements, you have to do it like this :

```
var normalCss = document.createElement('link');
normalCss.href = 'css/main.css';
normalCss.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/document.createElement) createElement only parses a tagName and not text.