# Is there any javascript event fired when the on-screen keyboard on mobile safari or chrome opens?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, on-screen-keyboard

I try to react to the on-screen keyboard in our web applications. Unfortunately there are some things complicating this:

First of all, the application has to run equally on mobile platforms (tablets) and desktops. Additionally scrolling the document/body is forbidden and to spice things up even more, landscape mode is mandatory on tablets.

So, if someone selects any input field, the on-screen keyboard opens up and blocks the sight on half of the page, therefor some inputs become invisible and I need to change that.

Unfortunately it seems, there is no event fired at all, which indicates, that half of the application just became invisible. I already checked scroll and resize events, but they didn't fire, too.

Of course, I could always react somehow as soon as I'm sure to be on a tablet. Probably 95% of the users will not attach a hardware keyboard anyway. But isn't there any cleaner way?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately the answer here is a clear: **NO**. There are some related questions here with some further information and tricks:

[screen styling when virtual keyboard is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556933/screen-styling-when-virtual-keyboard-is-active)

[iPad Web App: Detect Virtual Keyboard Using JavaScript in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593139/ipad-web-app-detect-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript-in-safari)

[Android/iPhone webkit, event triggered on keyboard pop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196195/android-iphone-webkit-event-triggered-on-keyboard-pop)

Answer (score 6):

On Android (sorry iOS), the resize event will fire when the keyboard resizes your page. Add an onresize event handler on your window and adjust the scrolling as needed.

Comment: window.onresize = function(e) {
          alert("resized");
    };
This isn't working, or do I miss something? iOS 14.7

Comment: Bummer @TristanG, seems this is Android only. I updated the answer. Please let me know when Apple catches up.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the ***focus*** and ***blur*** event?

So you can lock the min-height of the form (or other parent element) with a class when keyboard appears, and so the user can scroll touching screen when a input is selected.

I was looking for a similar issue, and this trick resolves my case. ✌

*** EDIT ****

As @mac used and exemplified us in the comment below

Comment: The focus event won't be fired again if the keyboard is closed without losing focus

Comment: In my scenario, I used focus on the input to imply that the keyboard was open and blur to imply it closed.  This worked fine for me.

Comment: You're also unable to detect the focus/blur events happening within iframes due to security

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea. If you know the screen is in a mobile size, you can detect when an input or textarea has the focusin and focusout event fired. If thats the case, the keyboard is probably opened.

jQuery example

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type="number"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], input[type="search"], input[type="url"], textarea')
  .on('focusin', function (){
    if(window.innerWidth < 800){
      // do stuff on keyboard opened...
    }
  })
  .on('focusout', function (){
    if(window.innerWidth < 800){
      // revert changes on keyboard closed...
    }
  });
```

Or using the height with any input type

```
let initHeight = window.innerHeight;

$('input, textarea')
  .on('focusin', function (){
    if(window.innerHeight < initHeight && window.innerWidth < 800){
      // do stuff on keyboard opened...
    }
  })
  .on('focusout', function (){
    if(window.innerWidth < 800){
      initHeight = window.innerHeight; // ensure initHeight is still accurate
      // revert changes on keyboard closed...
    }
  });
```