# How to scroll focused component in to view on showing On-screen keyboard in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onblur, onfocus, on-screen-keyboard

I have already got the expected behaviour. But not at all times. Sometimes the focused component is hidden behind the on-screen keyboard. I have fixed it by using `scrollIntoView` and `setTimeout`. This will help if the focused component is not scrolled up automatically.

My Solution:

```
    class KeyboardAwayView extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.dummyRef = React.createRef(); 
    }

    render() {
        const Children = this.props.children;
        // Scroll to children component on focus
        const ClonedChildren = React.cloneElement(Children, {
            onFocus: () => {
                this.dummyRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
                setTimeout(() => {
                    if (this.dummyRef.current) {
                        this.dummyRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
                    }
                }, (this.props.interval | 500));
            }
        });
        return (
            <div className="keyboard-away-container">
                {ClonedChildren}
                <div className="dummy" ref={this.dummyRef}></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

***Questions***:

1. Is there anything to do to improve my solution?
2. Is there any standard way to solve this. In React Native there is a *KeyboardAvoidingView*. Is there anything like that in ReactJS?

I have already gone through this [Is there any javascript event fired when the on-screen keyboard on mobile safari or chrome opens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132796/is-there-any-javascript-event-fired-when-the-on-screen-keyboard-on-mobile-safari).

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Is there any standard way to solve this. In React Native there is a KeyboardAvoidingView. Is there anything like that in ReactJS?

No, there **is not a standard way** to handle this in React (I assume you are referring to react-dom).