# Layout of html elements with enabled keyboard

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create an html element (let's say div) which will have responsive height and will be covered by enabled keyboard?

I have following situation:

[image]

And I'd want to have this div to be scrollable like that

[image]

I know I could do that by setting height of div to specifix px value but I'd want it to look the same on different mobile devices. I've tried to use `vh` but as I understand it corresponds to viewport height which is different with enabled keyboard. Is it possible to make viewport sizes not changable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The virtual keyboard is not HTML and is not in the DOM -- it's an operating-system level component and your page doesn't even know it exists.

Managing application layout is very difficult with the virtual keyboard unless you're building a native app. In that case the app can control the visibility of the keyboard and adjust its layout accordingly. On a normal web page this is virtually impossible.

Comment: Couldn't you detect page resize via jQuery (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28272408/3684265) and then just use jQuery to addClass/removeClass?

Comment: Damn, that's weird there is no such functionality. So everyone just managing it manually for each device separately?

Comment: Implementation varies from browser to browser. There is no reliable way to deal with this.

Comment: @imvain2 yea I thought about that but it seemed a bit too complicated, I was sure there should be some mechanism to automagically set it.

Comment: I literally spent weeks trying to solve this, and ended up going with hybrid app strategy.

Comment: That's why we get paid da big bucks :)

Comment: Haha, true that :)