# Click on input field triggers window resize

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have a header with logo, menu and search. When I'm on desktop I have all elements shown in that order, but if my window width is less than 980px, the menu hides (get's a toggle), and the logo is detached from the `nav` and attached after the logo. If the width is greater the logo is again detached and attached to the old place in the DOM.

```js
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
      if ($(window).width() < 980) {
        $('#search-container').detach().insertAfter('#logo');
      } else {
        $('#search-container').detach().insertAfter('#main_menu');
      }
    });
```

```css
#logo {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
#search-container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1px 10px;
}
#search-container .header_search {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 6px;
}
#search-container input {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgb(114, 114, 114);
  color: rgba(114, 114, 114, 0.5);
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: auto;
}
#search-container input:active,
#search-container input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
}
#search-container .submit {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}
#search-container .submit i {
  color: #d3031c;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo">Logo</div>

<div class="menu_wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul id="main_menu" class="">
      <li>Menu1</li>
      <li>Menu2</li>
      <li>Menu3</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="search-container" class="search-box-wrapper hide">
      <div class="header_search">
        <form name="search" id="search" method="get" action="#">
          <input name="s" type="text" placeholder="Search" value="Search">
          <a class="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Now the issue happens on mobile phones (and from the feedback, only on Android), when you tap on the input field to enter the search query, `resize` is being activated, and the search container detaches and attaches itself in the same space. And I have no idea why this happens. When I comment the part of the jquery code with the resize, I can type in the input field without the problem.

Why is resize being triggered on click? I checked the media queries, and I am not expanding the element in any way.

Comment: Did you use Bootsrap in this project?

Comment: This could be the cause of different browser plugins or extensions. (For instance I have found that Dashlane causes a resize when an input is clicked).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I still have no idea why this happens (the resize), but I found a solution:

I am turning off the window resize on `$('#search-container')` click event:

```
$('#search-container').on('click', function(){
    $(window).off('resize');
});
```

Stops the window from resizing (which was causing the issue), and you can type on android with ease now :)

Comment: No problem, happy to have helped :D :)

Comment: Could it be `bootstrap.js` that's doing it?

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because the soft keyboard opens when the input element is clicked.  Apparently `resize` triggers on a multitude of events, as described here: https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/resize_mobile.html.

Your solution works, but you could also use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32768730/2496827), i.e.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
   // If the current active element is a text input, we can assume the soft keyboard is visible.
   if( $(document.activeElement).prop('type') !== 'text') {
      if ($(window).width() < 980) {
        $('#search-container').detach().insertAfter('#logo');
      } else {
        $('#search-container').detach().insertAfter('#main_menu');
      }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to realize that the mobile keyboard was triggering a resize event. I found out just by commenting out the resize functionality. I have two search inputs on the page and funny enough this problem happens to only one input, the one that I was moving in to a side menu on resize.

So what worked for me was to create a global boolean that would be true if my input was clicked. Then in my resize function i check if my boolean is true and if it is I force focus the input, if it is not then I execute the resize logic.

```
var isClicked = false;    
function resize(){  
  if(isClicked){
      $('#search-input').focus().select();      
  }else{
    //resize logic
  } 
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    $('#search-input').click(function(){
        isClicked = true;
    }); 
    resize();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On iphones, if the font-size of input-field is less than 16px, the 'ios' auto zooms the page. Set the font-size of input-field to 16px to tackle this problem.

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted .... fixed my issue perfectly.. thx Telu