# Click on input field triggers window resize on android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have an input field in my cordova app. When I focus the input field by clicking on it, the window resize function is called on android. On iOS everything works fine.
The resizing makes problems because I have a text that is rendered with epub.js and it goes back to the beginning of the current chapter when clicking on that text field.

How can I prevent the resizing?

I tried this, but the problem is still there:
[Click on input field triggers window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280763/click-on-input-field-triggers-window-resize)

HTML:

```
<form id="realPageInputForm" ng-submit="goToRealPage(inputPage)">
     <input ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"     
           id="realPageInput" 
           class="inputPage input-label" 
           type="number" 
           name="inputPage" 
           ng-model="inputPage" 
           placeholder="Enter page here">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens beacuse when you click on that input, the keyboard appears and, in android, keyboard make your view smaller (screen size is shared between your app and the keyboard); and when keyboard hides the webview recover again their original size. You can check on other answers to questions similar to yours, like [PhoneGap: Is there a way to stop the keyboard from resizing the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076148/phonegap-is-there-a-way-to-stop-the-keyboard-from-resizing-the-view).