# Responsive website - ios fixed footer issue

Tags: html, ios, css, webkit, fixed

I have designed a responsive site which has three buttons which I need to be present all the time. The logical place to put them is fixed to the bottom of the viewport.
This works fine with position:fixed - but, when i click the buttons, they don't activate - instead, they are pushed up and the lower part of the webkit UI (save to home, bookmark etc) is revealed.

Also, when i scroll, and the same UI elements appear and disappear, my buttons temporarily stay floating above the footer, before jumping down after a second or so - which isn't pretty!

Is there a better way to fix buttons to the footer to allow them to be clickable?

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 1):

Jumping buttons are probably recounting position using javascript each time, where they should use css.

look here: [How do I stop my fixed navigation from moving like this when the virtual keyboard opens in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273098/how-do-i-stop-my-fixed-navigation-from-moving-like-this-when-the-virtual-keyboar)

When it comes to design however, I would recommend to not do that on the bottom. Users are used to having there IOS navigation not yours and even if you will find some way to differentiate, it will be really easy to miss the button and click IOS menu.