# <ion-footer-tab> with ion-tabs at bottom in ionic

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, keyboard

I am using ion-footer-bar in a ionic tab application in which tabs are positioned below. This footer is having a text-box in it. Now,in case of Android, when I tap on the text-box keyboard opens and footer shifts just above the keyboard. But not in case of IOS. I want to shift the footer above the keyboard when it opens. Please help.

Comment: something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27409350

Comment: i'm using keyboard-attach directive of ionic, it shows the white space above keyboard but not the input fields.Any idea..?

Comment: Did you find any solution. I have same scenario as like this. I'm using both tabs and ion-footer. Now I need to display footer below the ion-tabs. In footer just I need to add my company name. Working well in other device except iPhoneX 11.3 simulator.