# On Safari Mobile 10.3 sticky footer can be scrolled off the screen

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, mobile-safari

Our mobile web application has sticky bottom navigation like the one you often find in iOS applications, and after Safari 10.3 release **on landscape only** it is possible to scroll sticky navigation (footer) off the screen. Even though it is `position: fixed` and set `bottom: 0` it also wasn't possible on older Safari versions.

Styles for sticky nav / footer are following:

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

[DEMO to try on phone](https://output.jsbin.com/watikow/1)

In portrait mode it is always visible:

[image: portrait-mode]

In landscape mode you can scroll it off screen for the size of top address bar:

[image]

Has anyone come across such issue? I would appreciate any help to make footer stay on the screen. Thanks

Comment: I believe this is an iOS thing. Rather then a browser issue. Have you tried adding a wrapper div, and defining 'max-height'?

Answer (score 11):

There is nothing you can do about it. Safari's landscape mode makes the container with your content going off the screen. This is not detectable and therefore not to solve. I tried to illustrate what happens:

The blue bar = Safari's navigation bar

The yellow bar = Your app's navigation bar

[image: Situation safari]

Instead of shrinking the container's height, Safari lets it go off the screen.

Comment: That was pretty clear, but it doesn't help to solve the issue though. I hope maybe someone has some insight why this actually was introduced in Safari 10.3 and what to do about it. One possible way to solve this is to make container inside of body scrollable and body - 100% height static. But that would require complete re-implementation of our layout, something we would rather not want to do.

Comment: This is the best description of this problem I have seen yet.

Answer (score 6):

This is more a workaround than a real solution. However `position: fixed` has been a problem for mobile devices for years and the best way to overcome this problem is to use [`position: sticky`](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/).

> `sticky` behaves like `position: relative` within its parent, until a
>   given offset threshold is met in the viewport.

<sub>From: [Stick your landings! position: sticky lands in WebKit](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit)</sub>

**However** `position: sticky` is not fully supported yet, so I would suggest to use also:

```
position: sticky; /* currently in development for MS Edge */
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: -moz-sticky;
position: -o-sticky;
```

<sub>See status [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/positionsticky/) for MS Edge `sticky` support status (thank you [Frits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029176/on-safari-mobile-10-3-sticky-footer-can-be-scrolled-off-the-screen/44127427#comment75403858_44127427))</sub>

[image]

---

```css
html,
body {
  height: 200%;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #ededed 0px, #ededed 9px, #000000 9px, #000000 10px);
  background-size: 100% 10px;
}

footer {
  position: sticky; /* currently in development for MS Edge */
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  height: 50px;
  top: 80%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987153/how-to-stop-mobile-safari-from-setting-fixed-positions-to-absolute-on-input-focu

Comment: Unfortunately that solution has the same problem that OP's question

Comment: Also, `position: -ms-sticky;` will unfortunately not do anything as there is absolutely **no** support for the sticky positioning in Edge, with- or without the prefix. A bit sad really when you consider the fact that it's such a widely used browser....

Comment: I really do hope so @PaoloForgia ! I've looked it up a few times but MS seems to be incredibly tight lipped about if and when there will be support for it in the future. Unfortunately Microsoft doesn't have the greatest track record of keeping up with browser support so I am not getting my hopes up.

Comment: Oh I might just have to eat humble pie, I just found [this thread](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/positionsticky/) that says development on `position:sticky;` on Edge was started in March2017. Let's hold thumbs for a speedy resolution :)

Answer (score 4):

There is another way of creating a fixed element at the bottom of the page:

Set the `<body>` element (or whatever wraps your header, content and footer) to `display: flex; height: 100vh`. Then you take the footer and set it to `margin-top: auto`.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
    <main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
}
```

A different solution with the same markup would be to use CSS Grid:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
```

In order to get the best of both worlds you can wrap the CSS Grid styles in an `@supports(display: grid){}` wrapper. If Grid is supported the browser will take that and otherwise will fallback to Flexbox.

The best thing using this technique is that you won't run into overlapping contents, into zooming-issues and it is fully responsive from the get-go.

There is an article on CSS Tricks about the subject: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the fixed position element in your css:

```
transform:translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I already tried this but apparently this will solve the problem on older Safari, with this version the problem is different.

Answer (score 0):

Something that does happen on the switch to landscape mode, and the switch to and from safari's 'minimal UI' is a window resize event. You can check the `getBoundingClientRect().bottom` of the fixed element to see if it is greater than `window.innerHeight` (This means the fixed element is off of the bottom of the window). If so, you can set the css property `bottom` of the `fixed` element to `element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - window.innerHeight`. This will maintain to position of the fixed element. It appears to be a little jank to the user, but this is better than the element going off of the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it in a way that my tester is happy.
Not a perfect solution but doing its job.

Add an empty element with some padding or margin.

```
const _userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (_userAgent.indexOf('safari') != -1) {
    if (_userAgent.indexOf('chrome') == -1) {
        $('.myelem').append('<div class="my-5"></div>');
    }
}
```