# Prevent virtual keyboard from pushing content up

Tags: javascript, html, css, keyboard

I have website; a background image with an input. When I press on the input on my phone, the keyboard opens an everything gets pushed up. I would like instead the content to stay in place and keyboard just to go over the content without affecting(moving) it. I saw this solution:

```
input.onfocus = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I'm looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273098/how-do-i-stop-my-fixed-navigation-from-moving-like-this-when-the-virtual-keyboar) post, but I'll summarize the most useful parts for you:

Start off with the input's CSS as `position: fixed;`. When in focus, change it to `absolute`. Here is an example with JS:

```
if (document.getElementById("fixed") == document.activeElement) {
    document.getElementById("fixed").class += "absolute"
}
```

Of course, that relies on CSS:

```
#fixed {
    ...
    position: fixed;
}
#fixed.absolute {
    position: absolute;
}
```

I hope this helps!