# Jquery Mobile page, input field, fixed footer and keyboard hide

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Can anyone help me on what I think is a long standing problem with JQuery Mobile.

On my page I have a fixed header and fixed footer.  In the content I have two Input fields.

Regardless of what plugins I use I get the same problem.  When the keyboard appears if the user presses the 'done' button then things work fine. but if the user moves the focus from the input field by tapping on anywhere else on the view, the keyboard disappears but the 'footer' that should be at the bottom of the screen appears above the keyboard before dropping back down to its rightful place.

I have tried many things that have been recommended on here but I can't come up with a solution.

To reiterate, I am looking for the footer not to appear to slide down once the keyboard is hidden but should already be there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop my fixed navigation from moving like this when the virtual keyboard opens in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273098/how-do-i-stop-my-fixed-navigation-from-moving-like-this-when-the-virtual-keyboar)

Comment: Here is another related question: [Fixed persistent header and scroll to focussed input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861385/fixed-persistent-header-and-scroll-to-focussed-input-fields)