# HTML Bottom Navbar gets influenced by smartphone keyboard

Tags: html, css, position, navbar, smartphone

I have the following Navbar on the bottom of my website:
(from w3schools)

html

```
</div>
<div class="navbar">
<a href="WEBSITE_LINK"
 class="active">Home</a>

  <a href="#WEBSITE_LINK">News</a>

 <a href="WEBSITE_LINK">Site Notice</a>

</div>
```

css

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #ca3160;
  color: white;
}
```

If the smartphone user wants to type something in my textfield (above the navbar), the navbar gets pushed up by the upcoming keyboard. Therefore nearly the whole screen is blocked by the keyboard and the navbar. So how can I fixate the Navbar to the bottom even if I open the "keyboard"? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Set the HTML `body`'s height to `100vh`.

Comment: Post the CSS that you are using.

Comment: wow i actually forgot about the CCS file. Its here now.

Comment: @Zera it didnt change anything sadly

Comment: Is the formatting error in your HTML also in your real code?

Comment: Its not. and its embarrassing that i pastet 2 wrong codes. sorry for that

Comment: We all make mistakes, and it seems you left another one; there is an extra `>` before `class`.

Comment: ok so by the looks of it i messed up when I changed the link to `WEBSITE_LINK` I dont have an error in my real files sadly

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I stop my fixed navigation from moving like this when the virtual keyboard opens in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273098/how-do-i-stop-my-fixed-navigation-from-moving-like-this-when-the-virtual-keyboar)