# Mobile keyboard moves up an html element that is at the bottom - how to keep the bottom html element hidden below the mobile keyboard?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, responsive-design

[image]
[image]
Here is the css code:

```
const NavbarContainer = styled.div`
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -0.7rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 30%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 40%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 70%
  );
`;
```

how do i keep the navbar hidden bellow the keyboard when the keybaord appears?

Ideally I am looking for a solution using css or something that would be relativelly easy to do

Any help would be much appreciated!

I have thought on adding a piece of logc that would hide the element whenever user starts inputing anything, however it does not seem like an elegant solution more like me trying to ducttape a solution - i would probably use some sort of state variable and pass it to css if I decided to go this route.

Comment: Did you try with absolute instead of fixed ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop my fixed navigation from moving like this when the virtual keyboard opens in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273098/how-do-i-stop-my-fixed-navigation-from-moving-like-this-when-the-virtual-keyboar)

Comment: @VilleKoo to some extent it does, but the solution proposed by Fenton (bellow) is a lot better for my particular issue since I want to hide the element instead of stopping it from moving it (as in that other question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers commonly change the view height to adjust it for toolbars and keyboards. This means they make the viewport small to give space to the keyboard, rather than overlaying the keyboard.

They do this as it prevents items being unreachable when the keyboard is open.

You can handle the general use case by making your sticky elements conditional upon a minimum view height.

For example, if the view-height is less than a number you choose (such as `600px`) you hide the element using a CSS media query.

That way, it will be visible unless:

1. The keyboard is open, or
2. The user is on a super-tiny screen (perhaps their watch?!)

```css
@media (max-height: 600px) {
    .sticky-thing {
        display: none;
    }
}
```