# How to handle differences in iOS and Android Keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

For HTML/JS in mobile browsers, I'm having an issue where blur events trigger differently in iOS and Android. In iOS, a user can click on "Done" on the native keyboard, which hides the keyboard and causes the focused element to blur.

The same, however, does not happen when a user clicks the back icon in Android to hide the native keyboard; The elements that were previously focused keep their focus.

Is there a way to listen for the keyboard hiding and trigger a blur on the focused element? Or is there a way to force the Android keyboard to display a "done" button? Or is there a generally better solution?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Code?

Comment: Yes sorry my issue is HTML/javascript based.

Comment: @user2746900 Jack wants to know what you have tried...

Comment: @user2746900 why do you want to know when a keyboard disappears? If the system decision is not to tell you, so be it. The user shouldn't expect you to override the system decision.

Comment: I have events that currently depend on input blurring that should be dependent on whether or not the mobile keyboard is showing. I need a way to either detect keyboard down, or force a blur on keyboard down.

Comment: In order for the keyboard to go down, don't you need to click off the keyboard, and wouldn't that result as a blur?

Comment: On my android device, when the keyboard is open, there is a button in the bottom left where the back button usually is that closes the keyboard without blurring.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a solution would be to listen to the keydown event on the input, and check if the keypress is "Enter".

To do that, please refer to this :

[Enter key press event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript)

Comment: I am not looking for the user to press enter, I am looking for the keyboard hiding, which can be done without pressing enter. I do not believe the native "keyboard hide" button has a keydown/keypress/keyup event bound to it.

Comment: Hum yeah, sorry. I may have found a solution, but I'm not sure it's going to work for you. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593139/ipad-web-app-detect-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript-in-safari