# Detect Windows 8 on-screen keyboard with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a full screen web page which has an input field. When the user touches the input field, the Windows 8 on-screen keyboard appears. This behaviour is expected and necessary, but because of the keyboard, the input field is covered.

I want to be able to detect when the Windows 8 on-screen keyboard is present using Javascript so that I can handle moving the input field above the keyboard.

The input field is absolutely positioned on the screen, so the on-screen keyboard doesn't seem to alter the way in which the window sizes are stored.

Any and all information regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: I would also like to do this via Javascript because then I can move the input field back when the keyboard is dismissed (which might not be handled through a window press as it can be dismissed via the keyboard itself).

Comment: cant we assume that any click on the input would trigger the keyboard? you could attach a handler to the input whenever its focused move it up, when its blurred move it back down...

Comment: @Banana, it is definitely a possibility, but I was hoping for a more portable, reusable solution. However, I will use this if I can't find another way :)

Comment: Does the keyboard appearing trigger a `resize` event?  Does `window.height` or `document.height` change?  I haven't tested this, it was just a curious thought (and just a wild guess).

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I can only assume not as the absolute positioning of the input field doesn't change. I will test it and come back to you.

Comment: My Google-fu found this: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/keyboard-events-sample-866ba41c and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700405.aspx Not sure if this is for Win 8 apps or webpages, but maybe it's helpful?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, my Google-fu also found that, but it looks like a Windows Store app, not a standard website. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Could this be of help?

[iPad Web App: Detect Virtual Keyboard Using JavaScript in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593139/ipad-web-app-detect-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript-in-safari)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input').bind('focus',function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(10);
      var keyboard_shown = $(window).scrollTop() > 0;
        $(window).scrollTop(0);

     $('#test').append(keyboard_shown?'keyboard ':'nokeyboard ');
   });
});
```

I know it's for iPad but I guess there could be some workaround for a normal browser maybe?
Not my own idea it came from @LKM and I don't fully understand it anyway.