# Is there no reliable way to detect if the virtual keyboard is open on iOS in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, detection, virtual-keyboard

I have a use-case where I need to know whether a web application is on an iOS device  using a virtual keyboard. But there seems to be no good way of doing this without using browser sniffing, which I understand is not advisable.

The best solution on stackoverflow seems to be [this one from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593139/ipad-web-app-detect-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript-in-safari) and it seems to be a very hacky solution.

Is there really no better approach to this problem? Is the above answer still the best?