# How to make fixed-content go above iOS keyboard?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, google-chrome, safari

I can only find questions where people have the opposite problem.

I want my fixed content to go above the iOS keyboard.
Image of the problem:

[image: fixed content goes below keyboard on ios]

I want iOS to behave like Android.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Parent element css:

```
.parent{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Button css:

```
.button{
    position:fixed;
    left 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We can use [VisualViewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VisualViewport) to calculate keyboard height. So we can set fixed-content pos correct.

Small demo: https://whatwg6.github.io/pos-above-keyboard/index.html

Github Repo: https://github.com/whatwg6/pos-above-keyboard

Code snippet:

```js
  const button = document.getElementById("button");
  const input = document.getElementById("input");
  let height = window.visualViewport.height;
  const viewport = window.visualViewport;

  window.addEventListener("scroll", inputBlur);
  window.visualViewport.addEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);

  function inputBlur() {
    input.blur();
  }

  function resizeHandler() {
    if (!/iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
      height = viewport.height;
    }
    button.style.bottom = `${height - viewport.height + 10}px`;
  }

  function blurHandler() {
    button.style.bottom = "10px";
  }
```

```css
  html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  #button {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 10px;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<input
  type="text"
  inputmode="decimal"
  value="0.99"
  id="input"
  onblur="blurHandler()"
/>
<div id="button" onclick="inputBlur()">Button</div>
```

Problems: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/visual-viewport-api#the_event_rate_is_slow

Why not innerHeight?: [Iphone safari not resizing viewport on keyboard open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417778/iphone-safari-not-resizing-viewport-on-keyboard-open)

Comment: 5 years later ... and there it is! This is great and seems to have good support, thank you! Also, nice color on that button :)

Comment: Don't know what's happening but this made the button appear too high up on my website but looks to be working fine in the demo

Comment: This answer is almost correct, but it won't work when scrolling all the way down. The number of pixels has to be:
`window.innerHeight - viewport.height - viewport.offsetTop;`.
Feel free to update your answer.

Comment: When I copy the demo onto my own server, it won't work there. On focus, iOS Safari scrolls up a bit, putting space above the input field, and the button is not visible anymore. The exact same code. Extremely strange. Thanks for the pointer, though. I will build my own solution based on that.

Comment: Sorry, I have update my code snippet .

Answer (score 13):

Mobile Safari does not support position: fixed when an input focused and virtual keyboard displayed.

To force it work the same way as Mobile Chrome, you have to use position: absolute, height: 100% for the whole page or a container for your pseudo-fixed elements, intercept scroll, touchend, focus, and blur events.

The trick is to put the tapped input control to the bottom of screen before it activates focus. In that case iOS Safari always scrolls viewport predictably and window.innerHeight becomes exactly visible height.

Open https://avesus.github.io/docs/ios-keep-fixed-on-input-focus.html in Mobile Safari to see how it works.

Please avoid forms where you have several focusable elements because more tricks to fix position will be necessary, those were added just for demonstration purposes.

Note that for rotation and landscape mode, additional tricks are necessary. I'm working on a framework called Tuff.js which will provide a full-screen container helping mobile web developers to build web applications much faster. I've spend almost a year on the research.

By the way, to prevent scrolling of the whole window when virtual keyboard is active, you can use this super simple trick

```js
var hack = document.getElementById('scroll-hack');

function addScrollPixel() {
  if (hack.scrollTop === 0) {
    // element is at the top of its scroll position, so scroll 1 pixel down
    hack.scrollTop = 1;
  }

  if (hack.scrollHeight - hack.scrollTop === hack.clientHeight) {
    // element is at the bottom of its scroll position, so scroll 1 pixel up
    hack.scrollTop -= 1;
  }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
  // Avoid just launching a function on every scroll event as it could affect performance. 
  // You should add a "debounce" to limit how many times the function is fired
  hack.addEventListener('scroll', addScrollPixel, true);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  hack.attachEvent('scroll', addScrollPixel);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

h1>small {
  font-size: 50%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container>div {
  border: #000 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 48%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

```html
<h1>iOS Scroll Hack</h1>
<p>Elements with overflow:scroll have a slightly irritating behaviour on iOS, where when the contents of the element are scrolled to the top or bottom and another scroll is attempted, the browser window is scrolled instead. I hacked up a fix using minimal,
  native JavaScript.</p>
<p>Both lists have standard scrolling CSS applied (<code>overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;</code>), but the list on the right has the hack applied. You'll notice you can't trigger the browser to scroll whilst attempting to scroll the list
  on the right.</p>
<p>The only very slight drawback to this is the slight "jump" that occurs when at the top or bottom of the list in the hack.</p>
<div class='container'>
  <div id='scroll-orig'>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
      <li>13</li>
      <li>14</li>
      <li>15</li>
      <li>16</li>
      <li>17</li>
      <li>18</li>
      <li>19</li>
      <li>20</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id='scroll-hack'>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
      <li>13</li>
      <li>14</li>
      <li>15</li>
      <li>16</li>
      <li>17</li>
      <li>18</li>
      <li>19</li>
      <li>20</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Got this answer from [here](https://gist.github.com/avesus/957889b4941239490c6c441adbe32398)

Comment: can you have a look at [my site](https://bejebeje.com) please? I have used `position: absolute;` but when the iOS keyboard pulls up, it still pushes everything up.

Comment: It's a shame that apple has not fixed this yet. it's 2021

Comment: Apple is the new IE :(

Comment: Accorading to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417778/iphone-safari-not-resizing-viewport-on-keyboard-open.   window.innerHeight may not correct,so As of iOS 13 this appears to have been solved by using the VisualViewport API implementation.https://stackoverflow.com/a/59056851/7552246

Comment: +1 for the `addScrollPixel()` hack. The `Element.scrollHeight` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight#determine_if_an_element_has_been_totally_scrolled) say the safest way to check if you've scrolled to the bottom  is `Math.abs(element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight - element.scrollTop) < 1`

Comment: I have the same fixed element issue when keyboard is displayed in Chrome on iPad, so this seems like an OS issue and not a browser issue.

Comment: my god. deeply upsetting that such a basic usecase would require a year of research

Answer (score 7):

This is a well known problem, and unfortunately one must resort to hacky tricks like the accepted answer for now. The W3C is however in the process of specifying [The VirtualKeyboard API](https://www.w3.org/TR/virtual-keyboard/).

Note: At the time of writing, this answer is not *yet* ready for prime time. It's important to understand that this specification must also be forward looking, to adapt to the myriad possible virtual keyboards of the future. It may be a few years before reliable cross platform browser support begins to appear and this answer becomes the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted the whatwg's answer because it didn't work for my website (I don't know why exacly).
I use the property top instead of bottom for the absolute div.
My page is a chat, my div contains an input.

Here my solution:

```
// Only for Safari on iOS
// (use interactive-widget=resizes-content to fix Chrome)
if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') === -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') > -1) {

        // Put the body relative
        document.body.style.position = 'relative';
        let marginTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.body).marginTop);
    
        // My toolbar (in my case, a div with an input inside to make a chat)
        myBottomDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    
        // Events (touchmove on mobile, because the scroll event doesn't work well)
        window.addEventListener("scroll", resizeHandler);
        window.addEventListener("touchmove", resizeHandler);
        window.visualViewport.addEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);
    
        function resizeHandler() {
            myBottomDiv.style.top = (window.scrollY +  window.visualViewport.height - marginTop - myBottomDiv.offsetHeight) + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting solution to this problem.

The solution is to create a hidden input and focus on it on the touchstart event.

```
<input id="backinput" style="position:absolute;top:0;opacity:0;pointer-events: none;">
<input id="input" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;">
```

Using JQuery:

```
$('#backinput').on('focus',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    const input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.focus({ preventScroll: true });
})
$('#input').on("touchstart", function (event) {
    if(!$(this).is(":focus"))
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#backinput').focus();
    }
})
```

Finally, resize the viewport so that the bottom input moves above the keyboard (if needed)

```
window.visualViewport.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
    $('body').height(parseInt(visualViewport.height));
});
```

For me it works perfect. I am building a messenger.

Comment: Setting `height` on `body` has no effect to me. Also tried on `html`, no effect. (I tried using jQuery on Safari, and using Chrome DevTools)

Answer (score 0):

There is changing the bottom css prop when the keyboard is shown or screen is scrolled. It is not what you want but it is the best that I could realize)

Below you can see my React hook and its usage.

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

export const useFixedPositionWithOpenedIOSKeyboard = (extraBottomOffset = 10) => {
  const elementRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
      const setElementOffsetBottom = () => {
        const screenHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
        const screenHeightWithoutKeyboard = visualViewport?.height ?? 0
        const offsetTop = visualViewport?.offsetTop ?? 0

        if (elementRef?.current) {
          const elementStyles = (elementRef.current as HTMLElement).style

          if (Math.round(screenHeightWithoutKeyboard) < screenHeight) {
            elementStyles.bottom = `${
              screenHeight - screenHeightWithoutKeyboard - offsetTop + extraBottomOffset
            }px`
          } else {
            elementStyles.bottom = ''
          }
        }
      }

      const debounceElementOffsetBottom = _.debounce(setElementOffsetBottom, 150)
      const showElement = () => debounceElementOffsetBottom()

      window.addEventListener('scroll', showElement)

      return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', showElement)
    }
  }, [])

  return elementRef
}
```

...

```
export const Component = () => {
  const buttonRef = useFixedPositionWithOpenedIOSKeyboard();

  return (
    <>
      <input type='text' />
      <button type='submit' ref={button} style='
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 40px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%);
        transition: bottom 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
      '>
        This is Button
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I felt *whatwg's* answer pointed in the right direction of `visualViewport`, but I wanted to build something **with scrolling** (which has some extra challenges) and a bit more code clarity.

Check out a simple demo of the solution here: https://nnrh69.csb.app/

Essentially, it changes the element's `position: fixed` to `absolute` on iOS and then adjusts its location at *scroll* and *viewport-resize* events (while catching an additional scroll issue of mobile Safari).

**Here's the JavaScript essence:**

```
const fixedElement       = document.querySelector('#fixedElement');
const fixedElementHeight = fixedElement.offsetHeight;
const docHeight          = document.documentElement.scrollHeight + fixedElementHeight;  // Total height of the document (padding to be added manually)
let   fixedElementBottom; // Distance from top of the document to the BOTTOM of the fixedElement. Will change through scrolling and touch keyboard.

function adjustFixedPos() {
  fixedElementBottom = document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.visualViewport.height;
  // Limit the position to the end of the document, otherwise Safari lets the user to scroll without end
  if (fixedElementBottom > docHeight) { fixedElementBottom = docHeight; }
  fixedElement.style.top = (fixedElementBottom - fixedElementHeight) + "px"; 
}

// On iOS, switch to from fixed to absolute positioning which gets updated when needed.
if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
  fixedElement.style.position = "absolute";
  fixedElement.style.bottom   = "auto";
  adjustFixedPos();

  document.addEventListener('scroll', adjustFixedPos, {passive: true});
  window.visualViewport.addEventListener('resize', adjustFixedPos, {passive: true});  // Fires on touch keyboard extension and collapse
}
```

You can see the full code, including HTML and CSS, in [the demo](https://nnrh69.csb.app/). Open in mobile Safari to see the workaround in action. On any other browser, the native fixed positioning is in place.

I hope it helps, and someone spends less time than me (several days) on this : )