# Is there any fix to iOS, safari and chrome fixed position for when keyboard shows up?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, reactjs, viewport

I'm trying to put a fixed-bottom div that stays on bottom and gets above the virtual keyboard when the input field is focused. On Android, it works perfectly, but on iOS (safari and chrome) it doesn't seem to work at all.
I tried this solution from mozilla web dev:  [check second example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VisualViewport#examples) 
but this is the behaviour I'm getting on ios:

**at first**

[image: first look]

** after scroll and refocus input: **

[image: after a little scroll and then re-focus input]

It seems that on iOS the resize event is not triggered by the keyboard?

this is the code I'm using on React:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function CustomModal() {
  const [bottompos, setBottomPos] = useState('0')
  useEffect(() => {
    const bottomBar = document.getElementById('bottombar')
    const layoutViewport = document.getElementById('layoutViewport')

    // Function to update the bottom bar position
    function updateBottomBarPosition() {
      const viewport = window.visualViewport
      const visualViewport = window.visualViewport
      const offsetLeft = visualViewport.offsetLeft
      const offsetTop =
        visualViewport.height -
        layoutViewport.getBoundingClientRect().height +
        visualViewport.offsetTop

      // You could also do this by setting style.left and style.top if you
      // use width: 100% instead.
      console.log(offsetLeft)
      setBottomPos(offsetTop)
      bottomBar.style.transform = `translate(${offsetLeft}px, ${offsetTop}px) scale(${
        1 / viewport.scale
      })`
    }

    // Attach the update function to both scroll and resize events
    window.visualViewport.addEventListener('scroll', updateBottomBarPosition)

    // Attach the update function to the resize event of the window
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateBottomBarPosition)

    // Initial positioning
    updateBottomBarPosition()

    // Clean up event listeners when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      window.visualViewport.removeEventListener(
        'scroll',
        updateBottomBarPosition,
      )
      window.removeEventListener('resize', updateBottomBarPosition)
    }
  }, []) // Empty dependency array ensures the effect runs once when mounted

  console.log(bottompos)

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="bottombar" style={{ position: 'fixed' }}>
        <div> some bottom content here </div>
      </div>

      <div id="layoutViewport">
        <input type="textarea"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CustomModal
```

which is basically the same code as the example from mozilla dev.

[stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bfbgq5?file=src%2FApp.js)

The question is, is there a solution for this?  This has been bugging me out for a while now, and I can't seem to figure the solution to this

Comment: Have you tried implementing the basic behavior in a _non_-React project. I.e., is this because of the way you have it implemented with React?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to tweak [`interactive-widget` in your viewport meta](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-viewport/#interactive-widget-section):

- `overlays-content` is the default behavior: do not resize, put things on top
- **`resizes-content`** : resize the initial viewport (and thus also the virtual viewport)
- **`resizes-visual`** : resize the virtual viewport but not the initial viewport

As far as I can understand from reading the specs, most of us are interested only in the virtual viewport. So try `resizes-content` and then `resizes-visual`.

I think this applies to all widgets, so even floating overlaying buttons would be affected.

There's also `viewport-fit=cover`

Comment: I tried, with both of them, no change. Matter of fact, from what I see in console, on iOS, the resize doesn't happen ( as you can see, I'm logging ` console.log(bottompos)` to see what is the offset top, but on iOS, it's only logged once, showing the offset as the initial height of the page, after that, the offset is not changed anymore, also the transform stays the same, opposed to android, where the offset - and bottompos is logged everytime the input is focused )

Comment: Might not be supported, sadly. This explainer goes into more details about inconsistencies with iOS's behavior compared to other vendors: https://github.com/bramus/viewport-resize-behavior/blob/main/explainer.md#problem-statement

Comment: I read that whole conversation, with the IIRC logs too, as far as I'm able to grasp, there is no direct solution? Or am I missing something? I did some research on the topic too, reading multiple issues from git, and as a last resort, I returned to this solution form 6 years ago:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833049/how-to-make-fixed-content-go-above-ios-keyboard?fbclid=IwAR0FVRDop5kglJ6hV7NzMvGXgQpJmK-OT5E5SAhq2DHZ2tlxYcst428AUxw

But I was hoping for a better-performance solution, as this seems to be a little laggy

Comment: `interactive-widget` is supposed to be the fix, but if they don't support it there's no point sadly. Only weird hacks would make it truly cross-platform

Comment: interactive-widget is only supported by Chrome.