# How to detect or force to open keyboard on IPhone?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs

I am looking for answer hours already and couldn't find any good solution: I am using react js and redux and trying to solve this issue mostly for Chrome.

Component which is observing one of redux state, contains **Input** field and whenever I set in redux **focusInput: true** I am calling function with following code:

```
inputRef.current.focus()
```

It works on Android phone. Input field gets focused and keyboard pops up, but couldn't make it work for IPhone.

Found many articles around this topic but all seems like ugly workaround... one of example is on this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593139/ipad-web-app-detect-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript-in-safari?fbclid=IwAR11w-JVkVIBpW1vRBlMbmwWqJN3_WZIrAD1PmIsahY8qiKukmGhybxl8nk) .

Is there any good api for Mobile virtual keyboard or solution?